# trait in phpunit TestCase

Tags: php, phpunit

I dont understand the behavior of my code. Here is a simple version :

I have a test :

```
class EditVoterTest extends TestCase
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->getContainer();
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        // test lauched 4 times with a provider
    }
}
```

and a trait :

```
trait ContainerAwareTrait
{
    private $container;

    public function getContainer()
    {
        if (!$this->container) {
            echo "NO CONTAINER \n";
            $this->container = true;
        }

        return $this->container;
    }
}
```

and the result is

```
PHPUnit 5.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.NO CONTAINER
.NO CONTAINER
.NO CONTAINER
.                                                                4 / 4 (100%)NO CONTAINER


Time: 241 ms, Memory: 21.00MB
```

Why the container is "construct" each time ?

Comment: I think that, for every test, a new instance of the test class is being created.

Comment: For each test PHPUnit will run `setUp()`

Comment: As @FelippeDuarte said, `setUp` is the method designed to do all the necessary things before execute any test (instanciate an object, connect to a resource, etc). So, as the unit test means, each test has to be considered unique, So `setUp` has to be execute for each test.

Comment: I've never really deeply explored how test methods are launched. i added `static $counter = 0` and a `__construct()` with `self::$conter++; print 'being constructed '.self::$counter.' time';` to increment and print out the counter. Output says the class `EditVoterTest` is being constructed even 5 times, not 4.

Comment: Well, of course `setUp` is launched for each test, but the container creation should'nt be. I guess the $container will be static...

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, setUp() is called before each test. 
So it is usual behavior and is not related to trait.
Try this:

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    $this->getContainer();
    echo "it's called once a class";
}

protected function setUp()
{
    $this->getContainer();
    echo "it's called before each test";
}
```

The real difference for trait starts when you want to use its methods in data providers.
You will probably get an error that method is unknown since data providers are loaded before the constructor.
This will **fail**:

```
class EditVoterTest extends TestCase
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    /**
    * @dataProvider getData
    */
    public function testSomething()
    {
        // test something
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->getContainer();
    }
}
```